# Host a WPF control in activex instead of Win32 App

Tags: wpf, activex

I'm searching an example of an activex that contain a WPF control.

I'm able to see the control during registration of activex in the test activex container but when I instantiate it i cannot see WPF but what is coded inside OnDraw.

Any hint or example?

Answer (score 2):

Acording to "WPF 4 Unleashed":

FAQ: What about the reverse direction—exposing WPF controls as ActiveX controls?

There is no built-in support for this above and beyond HWND interoperability, so your best bet is to use your favorite means of creating a non-WPF ActiveX control (using Active Template Library [ATL], for example) and inject WPF content inside it.